# How can I target elements in a table cell using vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-table, vuejs2

I have a table that is dynamically being rendered with data in a readonly input box in each cell.  In the first cell, there is an edit button.  When the user clicks edit, the readonly on the input boxes should be disabled so data can be entered in each cell. The edit button should be hidden and the save button should show.  When the user clicks save, it should call a method that can use the data (save to a database or something).

I thought I could use the event and drill down to the target but it's an array and I'm not sure what to do.  Any ideas?

```
<div id="app">
<table border=1 width=100%>
  <tr>
    <td width=10px>EDIT</td>
    <td>Program</td>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td>Funding</td>
    <td>Funded</td>
    <td>Recruit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="program in programs">
    <td><button class="show" v-on:click="editItem($event)">edit</button>&nbsp;<button class="hide">save</button></td>    
    <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" readonly="readonly" v-model="program.program"></td>
    <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" readonly="readonly" v-model="program.company"></td>
    <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" readonly="readonly" v-model="program.funding"></td>
    <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" readonly="readonly" v-model="program.funded"></td>
    <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" readonly="readonly" v-model="program.Recruit"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data() {
    return {
      test:"hello",
      programs:"",
      hide:true
    }
  },
  created: function(){
    this.getPrograms();
  },
  mounted: function(){

  },
  methods: {
    getPrograms: function(){
     axios.get("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/isogunro/jsondb/Programs").then((response) => {
        this.programs = response.data;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    },
    editItem: function(e){     
      console.log(e)
       //console.log(e.target.parentElement.parentNode.parentElement.HTMLCollection) doesn't work
      alert("Make line item editable for editing and then saving")
    }
  }
})
```

Here's the [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/WNNOMeB?editors=1011) for reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i `forked` your pen [here](https://codepen.io/christiancazu/pen/vYYZRpE) or try it like this:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el:"#app",  
  filters: {
    toCapitalize (text) {
      return text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1)
    }
  },  
  data () {
    return {
      columns: [
        'program', 'company', 'funding', 'funded', 'Recruit'
      ],
      programs: []
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getPrograms()
  },
  methods: {
    getPrograms () {
      axios.get("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/isogunro/jsondb/Programs")
        .then(response =>
          // adding prop isEditable for each object    
          this.programs = response.data.map(program => ({ isEditable: false, ...program }))
        )
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    },
    // using index of the current program to toggle the property isEditable
    editItem (index) {
      this.programs[index].isEditable = !this.programs[index].isEditable
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.editable {
  border: 2px solid green
}
.button-action {
  min-width: 3rem
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table border=1 width=100%>
    <tr>
      <td width=10px>EDIT</td>
      <td v-for="(column, indexColumn) in columns" :key="indexColumn">
        {{ column | toCapitalize }}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(program, indexProgram) in programs" :key="indexProgram">
      <td>
        <button 
          @click="editItem(indexProgram)"
          class="button-action"
        >
          {{ program.isEditable ? 'save' : 'edit' }}
        </button>
      </td>    
      <td v-for="(column, indexColumn) in columns" :key="indexColumn">
        <input        
          v-model="program[column]"
          :readonly="!program.isEditable"
          :class="{ 'editable': program.isEditable }"
        >
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: it works great but could you explain what you did.  I don't quite get why you added the property ```isEditable: false```

Comment: was added for can set the `readonly` property reactive using his `boolean` value on each object.

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve a list of programs add an extra property that will indicate if row is in edit mode:

```
axios.get(url).then (response => {
    this.programs = response.data.map(item => {
        ...item,
        isEditing: false
    })
})
```

Also programs should be initialized to an empty array instead of empty string.

In editItem method, instead of event object you will pass an reference to item and then set isEditing to true

```
editItem(item) {
    item.isEditing = true
}
```

Then you can create method that will retrieve if row input is in readonly mode:

```
isReadOnly(item) {
    return item.isEditing ? false : "readonly";
}
```

Then bind this method to readonly attribute

```
<input type="text" :readonly="isReadOnly(item)" />
```

Avoid using node references and try to solve problem with binding. For example you can bind button title to method and return "Save" or "Edit" value depending on isEditing state.

Answer (score 1):

**Have a property to keep track of which program row is being edited.**
You can accomplish this by using your already available program.id property

The `editingId` vm property indicates which "program" is being edited. If the property is set to other than null, the `readonly` attribute will be `false` and the button is toggled from `edit` to `save`. If the `editingId` property is set to `null`, the table goes back to normal view mode.

I implemented a `saveItem` v-on:click callback to the `save` button just to set the `editingId` property back to `null`, to fully illustrate how it works. You can define the callback however you want, but remember to set the `editingId` property to `null` to get out of edit mode.

**Here is the [edited pen](https://codepen.io/santanamaick/pen/zYYzWeb?editors=1011)**

Comment: How would I get the value of the input box in the cells and the id for that row?

Comment: @OLA Just pass the id to the save button's callback. I edited the pen to demonstrate. To capture the value of the changed row just find the corresponding id in this.programs.

Answer (score -1):

Add a readonly attribute to the elements in an array.
Upon clicking the edit button, set the readonly attribute of the elements in the array to false.